# Creating a Learndash Group programmatically in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, learndash

I'm working on a WordPress project with LearnDash, and I need to create Learndash groups programmatically. I want to achieve this using functions or hooks in my plugin, rather than manually through the LearnDash admin interface.

Can anyone guide me on how to create Learndash groups programmatically using functions or hooks? I'd like to automate the process and ensure consistency in group creation.

Additional Information:

- I'm using the latest version of LearnDash and WordPress.
- I have basic knowledge of WordPress development and PHP.
- I have already tried searching the LearnDash documentation, but I couldn't find a clear solution for creating groups programmatically.

Any help or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!